# Does the Meebo Minibar use HTTPS?

Tags: https, ssl, meebo

I use Meebo my primary IM client anymore, and I always use it via HTTPS.  They rolled out a bunch of updates to the whole Meebo service today (most of which I'm not a fan of), but the new [Meebo Minibar](http://www.meebo.com/download) is a nice little browser IM client.  However if it's not HTTPS its not worth it, and I can't find any documentation as to whether the data sent by it is SSL encrypted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The MiniBar will not appear on sites that use HTTPS. If the url of the site begins with https:// rather than http://, the MiniBar will be disabled.

From the [MiniBar Browser Extension FAQ](http://www.meebo.com/support/article/159/) page.